# Rails doesn't see simple Coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am following http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html tutorial about jquery - I am trying to run the simplest thing suck as:

welcome.js.coffee

```
paintIt = (element, backgroundColor, textColor) ->
  element.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
  if textColor?
    element.style.color = textColor
```

and welcome index

```
<a href="#" onclick="paintIt(this, '#990000')">Paint it red</a>
```

this doesn't work too

```
<a href="#" onclick="paintIt(this, '#009900', '#FFFFFF')">Paint it green</a>
```

When I click it then color isn't changed. What I am doing wrong or what I didn't do ?

Comment: Well, in javascript a function with two parameters is not the same as a function with three.

Answer (score 0):

The best advice I can give is to firstly ensure the JS is being called, and then make it unobtrusive:

```
$("a").on "click", (e)->
    e.preventDefault()
    paintIt($(this), $(this).data("background"), $(this).data("foreground"))


<%= link_to "Paint It Red", "#", data: {background: '#990000', foreground: '#ffffff'} %>
<%= link_to "Paint It Green", "#", data: {background: '#009900', foreground: '#ffffff'} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically coffeescript output is wrapped in an anonymous function, so as not to pollute the global namespace. Your javascript should look like this:

```
(function() {
  var paintIt;

  paintIt = function(element, backgroundColor, textColor) {
    element.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    if (textColor != null) {
      return element.style.color = textColor;
    }
  };

}).call(this);
```

So it should NOT be working - the `paintIt` variable is inaccessible from `onclick` attributes. You would need to expose it to the `window` object for your example to work

```
paintIt = (element, backgroundColor, textColor) ->
  element.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
  if textColor?
    element.style.color = textColor
#expose as global
window.paintIt = paintIt
```

I believe that is just a first step though. Next would be to make the js unobstrusive and setup eventhandlers from within coffeescript. And then there is no need to expose as a global.

```
paintIt = (element, backgroundColor, textColor) ->
  element.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
  if textColor?
    element.style.color = textColor
# use DOMContentLoaded or jQuery's: $(document).ready()
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ->
  #find <a> tags and setup event listeners
)
```

Comment: If it is inaccessible from onclick, why it is in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html - tutorial from irails quide is wrong ?

Comment: it appears it's making some assumptions and leaving parts out - it doesn't even tell where the coffeescript file should be located, or its name - yet you have created welcome.js.coffee in `apps/assets/javascripts` correct?

Comment: Rails created it for me - I only addded code to welcome.js.coffee in  apps/assets/javascripts and index in welcome/index.

Comment: so are you using `javascript_include_tag 'welcome'` to load the js on the page?